# Using Dictionary in MonoTouch

Tags: ios, dictionary, xamarin.ios, aot

I am very confused on the MonoTouch dictionary limitation: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations#Value_types_as_Dictionary_Keys

My understanding that code like this is **not allowed**:

```
var foo = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

But I see code in books like this, which doesn't make sense:

```
protected Dictionary<int, CustomCellController> _cellControllers = new Dictionary<int, CustomCellController>();
```

Also, someone posted that if you use nullable types, it convers the values into reference so the following works (as long as the key is not null):

```
var foo = new Dictionary<int?, int?>();
```

That also doesn't make sense, because nullable types are structs which are value types.

So what are the real rules about using dictionaries on a device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no JITin is allowed on devices all code must be compiled with the AOT (ahead of time) compiler.

> My understanding that code like this is not allowed:

This limitation is about the difficulties, for the AOT compiler, of determining what will be used at runtime. Such code might work and you'll see such code in samples - but it can also fail depending on what you do with the code (creating a `Dictionary` is not the problem).

> So what are the real rules about using dictionaries on a device?

Using value-types means that the generated code cannot be shared (like it can for reference types). E.g. Using a generic `Dictionary` with `int` and  `long` requires separate code, while the same code can be shared for `string` and `CustomCellController`.

Finding what `Dictionary<int,int>` needs is not the issue (it's pretty clear). However it's often in the internals that things gets complicated, e.g. ensuring the right `KeyValuePair` is generated. Nested generics are also hard to get right.

This is why the *first* general workaround is to try to *hint* the AOT compiler about what's needed. If the AOT compiler can find code that requires it to generate what's needed then it will be available at runtime.

The next workaround is to try to use a reference type (e.g. a `string`) instead of the value-type (since that case is simpler to handle for the AOT compiler).

Finally the AOT compiler is getting better (by each release) and works continues to reduce this (and other) limitation(s). So what you read here might not apply in 3, 6, 12 months...

Comment: Thans for your response. Is this missing some code or do you mean all of the code above is not allowed?

Also, does that mean that var foo = new Dictionary<int, int>(); is allowed as long as it's not used in addition with generics?

Comment: It's not a question of allowed or not allowed. It's a question of the *required* code being generated or not. Basic usage works (easy to determine what's being used) but some scenarios (e.g. LINQ queries) might not work without additional workarounds. When in doubt try executing it on an iOS device. If it does not work then try the workarounds (and report it as a bug so we can look at it).

Comment: Thanks, I just had a question regarding your response above. It says "My understanding that code like this is not allowed:". Is that missing code?

Comment: Nope, it's a copy/paste (quote) of your questions. My text below is the answer to that part... until the next *grey* block (your second question).

Comment: Oooh, usability fail. Thanks!